# Looking for an FTP client with ablity of verifying

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I'm looking for an FTP client with the ability to automatically check the integrity of uploaded files.

Both server and client will be Windows machines.

Does such a FTP client exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FTP protocol does not support verification by design.

Generally speaking if the file attributes and sizes are identical, you can be reasonably confident they have been uploaded successfully and intact.

Beyond that if you can log onto the server and create MD5 checksums of the files and compare them to local copies, that will confirm for certain whether the files are identical.

Answer (score 0):

There is the new `HASH` FTP command ([based on this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bryan-ftpext-hash-02)) that is [supported by FileZilla server (but not the client)](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24807).

There are also some non-standard hash commands `XCRC, MD5/MMD5, XMD5, XSHA, XSHA1, XSHA256,XSHA512`, which are supported only by a few servers and clients:

- FireFTP (client)
- [ProFTPD + Checksum module](http://www.proftpd.org/module_news.html)
- ([full list here](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1890&start=30#p52330))